# Model not drawing when using Index Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl

When I pass my index data directly in `glDrawElements()` everything works fine. But when I use vao and vbo the model isn't drawn at all.

Not using vao and vbo and uncommenting the commented part works fine.

Below is the code

Global Stuff

```
#include<GL\glew.h>
#include<GL\freeglut.h>
#include"OBJFileParser.h"

GLfloat *vertexData;
GLuint* indices;
int size;
ObjParser* parser = ObjParser::getObjParser();
```

Rendering Function below

```
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -8);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,size,GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);

    //This works fine
    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Initialization Function below

```
void init() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(50, 1, 5, 20);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Just parsing the obj file
    parser->parseObj("file.txt");
    vertexData = parser->getVertexData();
    indices = parser->getIndices();
    size = parser->getIndicesSize();

    GLuint vaoId;
    GLuint vboId[2];

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
    glGenBuffers(2, vboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    //This works fine
    /*glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexData);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);*/
}
```

Main Function Below

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("My Window");
    glewInit();
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a silly mistake.
sizeof(pointer_to_an_array) gives weird results.
Just have to get size manually and it works.

Comment: No, `sizeof(pointer_to_an_array)` doesn't give "weird" results. It evaluates to ... _the size of the pointer to an array_.